# OpenSearch 1.3 > 2.3 upgrade, CloudFormation fails on domain update

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, amazon-opensearch

I recently updated our CDK code to move our OpenSearch cluster from version 1.3 to 2.3.  The cluster itself seems to have upgraded to a healthy state and is still accessible / usable by our application, but CloudFormation failed when attempting to update our domain resource with:

`Resource handler returned message: "Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: DP Nodes are OOS, Tags operation is not allowed"`

This kicked the stack into `UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED`, which is not allowed.  The cluster cannot be downgraded back to 1.3.

I'm struggling to find any information about this error it's kicking out and not quite sure how to resolve it to unblock the CloudFormation stack.

Things I have tried:

- Digging through CloudWatch logs only revealed information pertaining to queries.
- Forcing the rollback to occur without Domain resource.  This got me back to an `UPDATE_COMPLETE` state, but each subsequent deploy of this stack will cause it to fail again since the core issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an odd presentation of a permissions issue.  As I was reading through some docs, I stumbled upon [this section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/handling-errors.html#troubleshooting-tbac), which discusses changes to tag-based access control.

This lead me start looking into CloudTrail a bit and stumbled upon the exact error that was firing when this deploy happened.  It was a little odd because the assumed role granted admin access to CloudFormation, but the last line of this event record caught my eye:

```
"sourceIPAddress": "cloudformation.amazonaws.com",
"userAgent": "cloudformation.amazonaws.com",
"errorCode": "ValidationException",
"errorMessage": "DP Nodes are OOS, Tags operation is not allowed",
"eventSource": "es.amazonaws.com",
```

Upon adding `es.amazonaws.com` to the trust relationship of that role, the deploy fully re-ran successfully.

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Sadly this didn't work for me. Check here for a related Github issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/23794.

Comment: @Aleksi are you able to find any additional information in CloudTrail?

Comment: No, CloudTrail output looks identical to what you've pasted here.